# how to choose a basis set when calculating COHP?

Tags: vasp, plane-waves

I am trying to use the [lobster program](http://www.cohp.de/) to calculate COHP, according to the [explanation in the literature](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.24300), it is better to add unoccupied atom orbitals into the basis set.

> The initial step in projection is finding a suitable choice of local
> auxiliary basis functions. For reasons of simple chemical
> interpretation, LOBSTER employs minimal basis sets that nonetheless
> carry the correct nodal behavior in the core region, which is
> necessary to fit PAW wavefunctions. LOBSTER first came with contracted
> primitive Slater-type orbitals (STOs) fitted to atomic functions,14 a
> reasonable choice for post-processing bonding information. There are
> also systems, however, where the bonding situation requires additional
> basis functions which deviate from those of the corresponding free
> atoms. In elemental beryllium, for example, its 2p levels are
> unoccupied in the free atom. For bulk Be, however, the 2p levels do
> get involved into bonding and define the metallic character, so the Be
> basis set must also include 2p functions.

For example, here is an input file for lobster to analyze COHP between `Ni` and `Fe` elements, whose valence electrons are in `3d` and `4s` orbitals, but the input file also uses `4p` orbitals.

```
COHPstartEnergy  -10
COHPendEnergy     6
usebasisset pbeVaspFit2015
basisfunctions Fe 3d 4s 4p
basisfunctions Ni 3d 4s 4p

cohpbetween atom 1 and atom 2
```

My question is:

1. Could I also use `4d`, `4f` etc. for elements like `Ni` and `Fe`?
2. How should I decide how many unoccupied atom orbitals I should add into the basis set?

Comment: Please limit your post to one specific question. If you have any lingering doubts after receiving an answer, you ask an additional question in a separate post.